# How disable show warning message in shell?

Tags: shell, warning

Emacs 26.1
Every time when I start shell I get the next message:

[image]

How I can disable this message?

Comment: The picture you show answers the question, so please explain which part of that answer you don't understand.  Also, as mentioned in that same message, you should report this bug (via `M-x report-emacs-bug`).

Answer (score 6):

To suppress the warning first make sure the `warnings` library is loaded by entering <kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `warnings` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Then add the listed option to `warning-suppress-types`. Load the customization interface by entering <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `warning-suppress-types` <kbd>RET</kbd>. Add a new top-level list-item by pressing the top-most `INS` button, then add two nested items by twice pressing `INS` inside the new item. Enter `undo` in the first nested item, and `discard-info` in the second. Finally, press the `Apply and Save` button.

This should add something like the following to your `init.el` file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(warning-suppress-types (quote ((undo discard-info)))))
```

Comment: It would be nice if the INS buttons more clearly marked (or background colored) to show what they do.